# Clustering algorithms with distance matrix as input

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I need to cluster the graphs of countries around the world to find similarity.
The graphs are about covid-19 cases during the pandemic.
I need a clustering method that take distance matrix as input.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your question more precise. If possible, try to include a reproducible example, with a small distance matrix to test.

Anyway, You can use : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html with affinity="precomputed"

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [2, 0, 3], [3, 3, 0]])
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity="precomputed").fit(X)

clustering.labels_
```